# What enterprise architecture tools support DoDAF 2.0?

Tags: architecture, uml, data-modeling

What tools best support the [DoD Architecture Framework (DoDAF) Version 2.0](http://cio-nii.defense.gov/sites/dodaf20/index.html), including support for transfer of the architecture data in accordance with the DoDAF Meta Model (DM2) [Physical Exchange Specification (PES)](http://cio-nii.defense.gov/sites/dodaf20/PES.html)?

My initial research found that [MagicDraw](http://www.magicdraw.com/newandnoteworthy/updm/16.7) and [Casewise](http://www.casewise.com/ModelsAndFrameworks/EnterpriseArchitectureFrameworks/DODAF/) claim support for version 2.0; and several other tools have support for earlier (or unspecified) DoDAF/MoDAF versions including [Sparx Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/mdg/tech/updm/), [Troux](http://www.troux.com/company/news/pressrelease.asp?pr=051129_dodaf_pr.xml&parchive=2005), [IDS Scheer ARIS](http://www.ids-scheer.com/en/ARIS/ARIS_Platform/ARIS_Defense_Solution/3736.html), [Artisan Studio](http://www.artisansoftwaretools.com/community/standards/dodaf/) and [Rational System Architect](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/systemarchitect/features/asad.html).

Experiences with any enterprise architecture tools and DoDAF 2.0 would be appreciated.  The immediate need is for [Data and Information Viewpoint](http://cio-nii.defense.gov/sites/dodaf20/data.html) models (DIV-1, DIV-2/OV-7, DIV-3/SV-11), but models in the other Viewpoints will be developed.

Comment: @skaffman, why the removal of the enterprise-architecture tag?  It was relevant to the question and is a [commonly used term](http://www.enterprise-architecture.info/EA_Tools.htm) among the tool vendors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of May 2010, tool support for DoDAF 2.0 appears to be limited and [UPDM 1.0](http://www.omg.org/spec/UPDM/1.0/) (DoDAF 1.5 / MODAF 1.2) is [on track](http://www.omg.org/news/member-news/ART067-UPDM_standardisation-Final2.pdf) to become the [DISR](https://disronline.disa.mil/) (DoD Information Technology Standards Registry) standard.  UPDM 1.0 tool support is widespread (e.g. Sparx, Artisan, MagicDraw).

We have selected a tool that supports UPDM 1.0 for use now and will revisit DoDAF 2.0 later.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Enterprise Elements "Elements Repository" based in Oracle to read the published schema from OSD and automatically generate the schema as well as a complete schema based portal into the data.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  At first glance the dependency on Oracle may be an issue, but I'll investigate further.

Link: http://www.enterprise-elements.com/product_dodaf.html

Answer (score 2):

Support for IBM Rational System Architect is very poor.  Training is very expensive.  Other assistance is very expensive.  Cannot recommend this tool.

In past years, I have been happier with ViTech CORE.  You may consider this one as well.

NOTE: The original answer above was posted in July 2010 when System Architect did not yet support DoDAF 2. It released support in mid 2010 and has had several updates to the support in major and minor releases since then; it supports all views of DoDAF 2.0 with direct data centric support for the DM2. Free training workshop is available here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/wikis/home?lang=en_US#/wiki/Rational%20Enterprise%20Architecture%20Wiki

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to ViTech CORE (http://www.vitechcorp.com/).  Their DoDAF support appears to be for version 1.x, not 2.0.  See table 2, page 8 in http://www.vitechcorp.com/support/docs/2006%20A%20Natural%20Approach%20to%20DoDAF_09.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes OMG's UPDM 1.0 specification was released December 2009.  UPDM 1.0 supports DoDAF 1.5 and MODAF 1.2

OMG UPDM 2.0 specifically supporting DoDAF 2.0 (actually 2.0.2, February 2010) has been submitted to OMG this week and will be discussed & voted on at upcoming September 2010 OMG Technical Meeting.  OMG will then go through a "finalization" process of gathering & resolving issues. This version supports the new DoDAF MetaModel (DM2) (based on IDEAS, etc.). Model transfer is supported through OMG XMI. Next sub-version will also support mapping to the DoDAF PES. This process will probably take 6 to 9 months. A number of tool vendors have signed a letter of intent to implement DoDAF 2.0

If you want to preview UPDM 2.0 specification -- subject to changes (issue by issue), see
http://www.omgwiki.org/UPDMAlpha/lib/exe/mediamanager.php?ns=doc:reference:submission . Again remember this is the preview of the specification that the OMG tool vendors will be implementing.

Len Levine

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true that it is taking vendors a bit of time to implement DoDAF 2.0.  The International Defence Enterprise Architecture Specification (IDEAS), a formal extensional, 4-dimensional foundation ontology takes a while to figure out.  However, it is very powerful and is being adopted by MOD and probably in the future by NATO.  Current status with tools as I know it:

Casewise Modeler -- http://www.casewise.com/Products/DoDAF/ demo-ed their DoDAF 2.0 product Summer 2010

Rational System Architect demo-ing their DoDAF 2.0 product to DoD CIO DoDAF team 9 Nov 2010

OMG and DoD are working together on UPDM 2.0 and it is progressing nicely as of UPDM Meeting with DoD in Cheltenham UK 1-3 Nov 2010

Other vendors:  development, repository, analysis/M&S have engaged (e.g, Metastorm), are being engaged or are being tee'd up.  The next DoDAF Plenary in Feb 2011 will feature vendors from these three categories.

As well there are some bare-bones tools to help vendors, repository developers, and analysis tool / M&S at www.silverbulletinc.com/dodaf-dm2, including DDL scripts for Oracle and SQL Server, to create tool backends or repositories.

Comment: Thanks for the status update on DoDAF 2.0 vendor implementations.  We've adopted UPDM 1.0 for now while we wait for the vendors to catch up with the standards.

Answer (score 0):

Sparx Enterprise Architect 8 does not support DoDAF 2.0.  On May 10 2010, support@sparxsystems.com responded to my inquiry with the following information for Sparx:

> Support for UPDM 1.0 (DoDAF 1.5 / MODAF 1.2) has recently been implemented for Enterprise Architect 8.  Enterprise Architect 8 and the UPDM Add-In are now available to download from our website.
>
> There is no development as yet to support DoDAF 2.0, however there are plans to investigate this in the near future.  We cannot confirm if/when DoDAF 2.0 support may be made available at this time.

UPDM is the Object Management Group (OMG) [Unified Profile for DoDAF and MODAF](http://www.omg.org/spec/UPDM/1.0/).

Comment: UPDM 2.0 is now supported in Sparx (Level 0 only) via an MDG technology plugin: http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/mdg/tech/updm2/

Answer (score 0):

Check out CORE software from Vitech.   It supports all the necessary diagrams and charts and can produce complete DoDAF 2.0 reports with built in scripts.

Answer (score -3):

I don't understand why you don't map your database to your UML model (e.g. adding stereotype such Entity, Session etc...) and then use object mapper such Hibernate to generate the database ?
The advantage is to only have one model and generate a reliable database because of the use of a standard and robust mapper (e.g. Hibernate). I agree that this solution only works with Java and not other languages but it works really well. You can also just add this information in UML and let the DBA do the integration job. 
UML database stereotypes can make life easier and better :-)

Comment: Multiple legacy databases and web services exist without a UML data model.  The goal is to create a data model of a new system that can be shared with multiple development contractors.  I'm looking for a tool to build the data model that supports DoDAF version 2.0.  The DIV-3 Physical Data Model (formerly SV-11) can be a stereotyped UML class diagram that can potentially be used for generating the database schema (and/or reverse-engineered from the database schema) as you suggest.

Comment: This post misses the point - the requirement is to model using the DoDAF 2.0 standard.

Comment: Hi Peter. Yes, I agree that if the point is only DoDAF then my post is out of topic :-)